# Core Data and multiple thread programming

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data, thread-safety

I know this is not a new topic, but I have not found a clear answer on my problem.

I am working on a project, which has a Core Data Model containing "Book". So when I downloading json data through network, I want to store these Book models in my core data (of course in background thread to not block the UI) and then pass these Book models to my controller and load table.

However, when I had learned the Core Data Reference of Apple, I get confused. The document says that I should not pass managed object between context. But I have two context, one for main thread and one for background thread which is used to download, store data and fetch current updated data. So what I should do is fetching managed object ids in background, and  passing these ids to context in main thread, and then get managed object with these ids in main thread.

Here comes the problem. Would getting managed object with id in main thread block UI? When I get managed objects with their ids in main thread, am I accessing the SQLite? And if some of these fetched managed objects are fault, which means I may do IO if I want to get their property, I think it still block my UI.

So, what is a practical pattern to use Core Data to fetch data in background and show these data in main thread (UI operation should be in main thread) without blocking UI?

Thank you for any help!

---

Rethink:

***Actually all the answers have not resolved my problem.***
However, I am back to a consideration that when we need to use multiple thread programming in core data. For most situation, maybe it is efficient enough to just use core data straight forward. I have overestimated the cost of core data operation in main thread.

However, still, I want someone to recommend a practical pattern to do fetch in background, and display in main thread. I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how many inserts you do into your database.

I found it working best to do all the downloading in a background thread, and then insert the objects in the main thread. As long as it's only a few hundred updates every 30 minutes, you should be fine with the influence on the UI performance. In my experience the robustness and simpleness of doing it like that outweighs by far the small performance impact on your main thread - you don't have to care about synchronizing contexts, making sure you use the right object in the right thread etc.

Comment: I think this is helpful. In my case, when user pull to load more, I will download 50 books and insert core data and show all books in my UI. I think to Core Data 50 items are just small amount of data. However, I am considering if I download all the books when user first launch app, just doing all these in main thread maybe very heavy.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, I would use three MOCs.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *worker = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyTyep];
worker.persistentStoreCoordinator = // your PSC
NSManagedObjectContext *main = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
main.parentContext = worker;
```

Then, whenever you want to perform background stuff, create a background MOC as a child of the main MOC.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *background = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
background.parentContext = main;
```

Remember, saving a context only saves one level.  So, when you save the background context, changes will be automatically pushed into the main context.

You can then save the main context whenever you want... but at some point you need to save the worker context.  `UIManagedDocument` handles the main/worker save interaction for you automatically (but you give up some control when using it).

The other benefit you get here is that the actual IO operations are not happening in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 2 questions on your answer.
First, which context should I use to do fetch operation, and then how to display the result.Second, what is the role of "worker" context.
@Jody

Comment: Connect your `NSFetchedResultsController` to the main MOC -- it runs on the main thread, which is where you want your UI stuff.  The background context is what you will use for adding your items downloaded from the network.  The worker context is so that the actual IO operations are done in a background thread, and not on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

First, keep it simple, you don't want juggle contexts in order to fix an issue you do not have. Yes, fetch on main thread will block UI, but unless you found this to be a real problem on real hardware, you can ignore it. If your fetch is indeed so heavy that it takes a noticeable amount of time, then profile and optimize, there are a lot of info out there, look at WWDC '12 videos on Core Data and Instruments and excellent Marcus Zarra [book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data).

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your data downloading in your background thread and then perform your update / insert operation in your main thread

Comment: This answer hardly helps OP. Can you provide some more info.

Comment: So when I update and insert in my main thread, I may block my UI. Furthermore, what I get worrying about is actually fetching in main thread. If I do fetching in main thread, it would block UI. But if I fetch in background and pass ids to main thread, and then in main thread get managed objects with these ids, would I still block my UI??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but give this blog entry over at the wonderful Cocoa is my girlfriend blog a try: [Core Data and Threads, Without the Headache](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/)

It explains some approaches to this problem and also deals with the UI and main thread question.

Comment: Just a heads up, while the post provides some good design, it is old and most of the stuff was implemented in iOS5 with new child/parent MOC model, although they say that it's only usable starting ios6 :)

Comment: This answer could have been a comment, and it'd be just as useful.  It has no content of its own.